# How perform basic authentication with SMF.Net.WebClient?

Tags: smartface.io

With SMF.Net.WebClient how I can perform basic authentication?

```
webClient_Validation.requestHeaders = ['Content-Type : application/json','WWW-Authenticate ' + credentialsEncoded];
```

or

```
webClient_Validation.requestHeaders('Authenticate ' + credentialsEncoded)
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "these don't work" can be assumed, but *how* do they not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 1):

There are documents about webClient object and it's properties.

You can check the links below :

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/data-network/rest-services-2/
http://docs.smartface.io/html/P_SMF_Net_WebClient_requestHeader.htm

Also, you can check the Smartface in Action project, there are webClient objects in it. You will open it from the Welcome page in Smartface App Studio.